# Symfony checking entity invariant before saving

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a course scheduling application.

"A person must have an application for the current semester before being allocated".

Allocation has many semester weeks. Semester week has one semester. 
Allocation has one person. 
Application has one person.

My 'code thought' is to add this to the allocation entity. It obviously won't work because it is wrong to use entity manager in the entity.

```
/**
 * Invariant is that a person must have a valid application for the specified semester.
 *
 * @ORM\PrePersist()
 * @ORM\PreUpdate()
 */
 public function validatePersonApplication() {
    $semester = $this->getSemesterWeek()->getSemester();
    $existing_application = $em->getRepository("CamsBundle:Application")->findOneBy(
  array(
        'person' => $this->person,
        'semester' => $semester
    )
  );

  if (!is_object($existing_application))  {
      throw new Exception("Can't allocate a session to a person without an application.");
   }
}
```

How do you test this condition before saving?

Comment: You should delegate all this logic to a service that should handle the allocations

Comment: I suggest you implement manager classes (as services) for each root entity that will handle business logic, that way it will be easy to control your app's logic.

Comment: Create a 'persistAllocation' service? that then calls the persist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed the suggestion by Vadim and created a service. Watch out though, this isn't great for extending the domain as 'symfony ensures there is a single instance' so any transient data that is part of the business logic can't really go in services.

I still need to reach into kernel to get the container to call the service. My post-update database event listener.

Running the debugger, it looks as though only one PrePersist event gets handled. All actions are triggered from the one function.

Entity method

```
/**
 * Automatically update the updated time.
 *
 * @ORM\PrePersist()
 * @ORM\PreUpdate()
 */
public function updateUpdated() {
  $this->setUpdated(new DateTime());

  // Validate class
  $this->_validateClassSession();

  global $kernel;

  if ('AppCache' == get_class($kernel)) {
    $kernel = $kernel->getKernel();
  }

  $allocationValidator = $kernel->getContainer()->get('allocation_invariants');
  $allocationValidator->validatePersonApplication($this->semesterWeek, $this->person);
}
```

Setup in services.yml

```
allocation_invariants:
  class: Interlated\CamsBundle\Services\AllocationInvariants
  arguments: ['@logger', '@doctrine.orm.entity_manager']
```

The 'service' implementation

```
namespace Interlated\CamsBundle\Services;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Exception;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Log\LoggerInterface;
use Interlated\CamsBundle\Entity\SemesterWeek;
use Interlated\CamsBundle\Entity\Person;

class AllocationInvariants {

public function __construct(LoggerInterface $logger, EntityManager $entityManger) {
  $this->logger = $logger;
  $this->entityManager = $entityManger;
}

 /**
 * Invariant is that a person must have a valid application for the specified semester.
 *
 */
 public function validatePersonApplication(SemesterWeek $semesterWeek, Person $person) {
   $semester = $semesterWeek->getSemester();
   $existing_application = $this->entityManager->getRepository("UnswCamsBundle:Application")->findOneBy(
   array(
    'person' => $person,
    'semester' => $semester
   )
 );

 if (!is_object($existing_application))  {
  throw new Exception("Can't allocate a session to a person without an application.");
 }
 }
}
```

This invariant is still in the domain class as it doesn't need to do a query

```
/**
 * Invariant is that the semester week must be for a semester that this course is allocated to.
 *
 * It looks as though multiple PrePersist() annotations don't work. Only the first is being fired.
 */
protected function _validateClassSession() {
    $semester = $this->getSemesterWeek()->getSemester();
    $courseSemesters = $this->classSession->getTeachingClass()->getCourse()->getSemesters();
    foreach($courseSemesters as $courseSemester) {
      if ($semester == $courseSemester) {return;}
    }

    // Failed to match the course to the current semester.
    $course_semester_names = "";
    foreach($courseSemesters as $courseSemester) {
      $course_semester_names .= $courseSemester->getName() . " ";
    }

    throw new Exception("Trying to make an allocation to a course that is not running in the specified semester. SemesterWeekNumber "
      . $this->semesterWeek->getNumber() . " with semester " . $semester->getName() . " The course is running in the following semesters : " . $course_semester_names);
 }
```